# Pepper naoqi 2.5 onConsoleMessage null

Tags: javascript, python, pepper

I am trying to print in python the messages from the web console using a callback on a onConsoleMessage event. Pepper (Edit: version 1.6) is running naoqi 2.5.5.5. I've modified the [executeJS](http://doc.aldebaran.com/2-5/naoqi/core/altabletservice-api.html#ALTabletService::executeJS__ssCR) example as a test. The problem is I keep getting null for the message in the callback. Is it a bug that has been fixed in a newer version of naoqi ? I've had a look at the release notes but I didn't find anything.

Here is the code I am using:

```
#! /usr/bin/env python
# -*- encoding: UTF-8 -*-

"""Example: Use executeJS Method"""

import qi
import argparse
import sys
import time
import signal

def signal_handler(signal, frame):
        print('Bye!')
        sys.exit(0)

def main(session):
    """
    This example uses the executeJS method.
    To Test ALTabletService, you need to run the script ON the robot.
    """
    # Get the service ALTabletService.

    try:
        tabletService = session.service("ALTabletService")

        # Display a local web page located in boot-config/html folder
        # The ip of the robot from the tablet is 198.18.0.1
        tabletService.showWebview("http://198.18.0.1/apps/boot-config/preloading_dialog.html")

        time.sleep(3)

        # Javascript script for displaying a prompt
        # ALTabletBinding is a javascript binding inject in the web page displayed on the tablet
        script = """
            console.log('A test message');
        """

        # Don't forget to disconnect the signal at the end
        signalID = 0

        # function called when the signal onJSEvent is triggered
        # by the javascript function ALTabletBinding.raiseEvent(name)
        def callback(message):
            print "[callback] received : ", message

        # attach the callback function to onJSEvent signal
        signalID = tabletService.onConsoleMessage.connect(callback)

        # inject and execute the javascript in the current web page displayed
        tabletService.executeJS(script)

        print("Waiting for Ctrl+C to disconnect")
        signal.pause()

    except Exception, e:
        print "Error was: ", e


if __name__ == "__main__":
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument("--ip", type=str, default="127.0.0.1",
                        help="Robot IP address. On robot or Local Naoqi: use '127.0.0.1'.")
    parser.add_argument("--port", type=int, default=9559,
                        help="Naoqi port number")

    args = parser.parse_args()
    session = qi.Session()
    try:
        session.connect("tcp://" + args.ip + ":" + str(args.port))
    except RuntimeError:
        print ("Can't connect to Naoqi at ip \"" + args.ip + "\" on port " + str(args.port) +".\n"
               "Please check your script arguments. Run with -h option for help.")
        sys.exit(1)
    main(session)
```

Output:

```
python onConsoleMessage.py --ip=192.168.1.20
[W] 1515665783.618190 30615 qi.path.sdklayout: No Application was created, trying to deduce paths
Waiting for Ctrl+C to disconnect
[callback] received :  null
```

Did someone face the same issue?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have the same issue. You can easily reproduce it by opening two ssh consoles on the robot, and on the first one executing

```
qicli watch ALTabletService.onConsoleMessage
```

and on the second

```
qicli call ALTabletService.showWebview
qicli call ALTabletService.executeJS "console.log('hello')"
```

... and instead of "hello", you will see "null" appear in your first console.

HOWEVER - if your goal is to effectively test your webpage, what I usually do is just open the page on my computer and use the chrome console (you can set chrome up to act as if the page was a tablet of the right size, 1280x800); you can do this while still connecting the page to Pepper, as if it was on her tablet, [using the method described here](https://github.com/pepperhacking/studiotoolkit/blob/master/doc/js_robotutils.md#remote-debugging). This is enough for 99% of the case; the remaining 1% is things where Pepper's tablet is actually different from Chrome.

Comment: Thank you for this workaround. It's true that most of the testing can be done on the computer's browser. I noticed that you are working at Aldebaran. Do you have any insight on whether this will be fixed? Thanks